# AD DNS records are not visible in GUI

Tags: domain-name-system

We have our AD DS and DNS roles installed on one server.

All of the sudden, DNS records are vanished from DNS Manager GUI.

The records are still in `mydomain.com.dns` file in `C:\Windows\System32\DNS` folder and everything works fine but DNS Manager is showing **just** one `SOA` and one `NS` records pointing to the server itself.

I've tried reloading/restarting to no avail.

Please assist.